# Where is the location of schema file for http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've been googling for the schema file that describes WPF elements for XAML but cannot find it.  The namespace declaration should has a list of all  WPF features, for example types, attributes, or elements that it adds to standard XAML.

I can find the schema file for XAML in Visual Studo cache directory.  The file is called *xaml2006.xsd*.  There is a *wpfe.xsd*, but its target namespace is *http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007*.

This may sound trivial, but I've spend hours to find this schema file.  Where can I found a schema file (XSD file) with targetNamespace set to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"?  If it is hidden inside DLL file, then perhaps there is an open source resource that host this schema file?

Comment: At me, here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas`.

Comment: May I know the file that contains declaration WPF schema in that folder?

Comment: Looking for that declaration, I think in the file `wpfe.xsd`.

Comment: But in that file, the `targetNamespace` is set to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007`.  I think that mean it should be referenced in XML by `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"`.

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc917841(v=vs.95).aspx) about this `targetNamespace`. Quote: `The latter namespace is supported for legacy reasons; new applications should use http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`. This namespace is used more in `Silverlight`.

Comment: And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd728664(v=vs.95).aspx). Quote: `The Silverlight default XAML namespace is identified by http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation when seen in xmlns mappings. For legacy support reasons, the http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/ identifier is treated as equivalent for identifying the Silverlight default XAML namespace.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508755/http-schemas-microsoft-com-winfx-2006-xaml-presentation-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little late, hope this tutorial will be helpful who search for this : 
First NS you mentioned is the default namespace. and it doesn't exist in that URL provided, but its a unique name , etc.

http://video.ch9.ms/ch9/ff6f/e1477e72-b989-49c1-acdd-62802c36ff6f/ABSWP81Part3_mid.mp4 Skip to 14.00

He says basically to use `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml`:

```
<Page 
    x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HelloWorld"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
?>
```

Comment: What about 2009?